DML Statements Inside Loops Issue in Salesforce Apex Code
While performing a Checkmarx scan on our Salesforce Apex codebase, an issue was reported under the category "DML Statements Inside Loops." Provided lot of lines of code as shown below.
But upon analysing my code, the DML statement update attachmentsToUpdate; and the method which it exist are not iterating/associated with any loop.
And moreover I am not understanding the issue at which line raising. How can I resolve this.
Thanks in advance.
DML Statements Inside Loops result path 1:

Object: foreach in file: classes/Util.cls
L 1000: for (Sobject odr : orders ) {
Object: jsonstr in file: classes/Util.cls
L 1039: jsonObj = (EntitlementWrapper) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, EntitlementWrapper.class);
Object: jsonobj in file: classes/Util.cls
L 1042: jsonObj.status = 'Draft';
Object: jsonobj in file: classes/Util.cls
L 1301: createQuoteEntitleMent(JSON.serialize(jsonObj), processingQuote, 'create');
Object: requestbody in file: classes/Util.cls
L 801: public static void createQuoteEntitleMent(String requestBody, SObject odr, String operation){
Object: requestbody in file: classes/Util.cls
L 836: request2.setBody(requestBody);
Object: request2 in file: classes/Util.cls
L 838: system.debug('DML request body-->' + request2.getBody());
Object: request2 in file: classes/Util.cls
L 839: HttpResponse response = http2.send(request2);
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 840: system.debug('status=' + response.getStatus());
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 841: system.debug('getStatusCode=' + response.getStatusCode());
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 842: system.debug('response body=' + response.getBody());
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 843: if (response.getStatusCode() == 201 || response.getStatusCode() == 200){
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 844: Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
Object: response in file: classes/Util.cls
L 880: attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(response.getBody());
Object: attachment in file: classes/Util.cls
L 881: attachment.Name = String.valueOf('JSON_' + system.today() + '.json');
Object: attachment in file: classes/Util.cls
L 882: attachmentsToUpdate.add(attachment);
Object: attachmentstoupdate in file: classes/Util.cls
L 902: if(!attachmentsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
Object: attachmentstoupdate in file: classes/Util.cls
L 904: update attachmentsToUpdate;

public static void createQuoteEntitleMent(String requestBody, SObject odr, String operation){
        
    try{
            checkUserInfo();
            SObjectType quoteObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Quote');
            if (!quoteObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
                Object[] data = new Object[] { 'Update', 'Quote', 'table'  };
                throw new SentinelException(string.format(permissionErrorMessageFormat, data));
            }
                Http http2 = new Http();
                HttpRequest request2 = new HttpRequest();
                if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase('create')) {
                    request2.setMethod('POST');
                } else {
                    request2.setMethod('PUT');
                }
                String path = '/ent';
                String uri = Test.isRunningTest() ? 'http://callout.' + TokenHelper.SCNAMEDCREDENTIAL_DEVELOPERNAME + '.com' + path : 
                    'callout:' + TokenHelper.SCNAMEDCREDENTIAL_DEVELOPERNAME + path;
                request2.setEndpoint(uri);
                request2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request2.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
                request2.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
                request2.setHeader('RequestClient', Client);
    
                system.debug('++eid entered ' + odr.get('EID__c'));
    
                request2.setHeader('guid', newGuid());
    
                if (rd[0].Request_Timeout__c != null) {
                    system.debug('Requesttimeout-->' + Integer.valueOf(rd[0].Request_Timeout__c));
                    request2.setTimeout(Integer.valueOf(rd[0].Request_Timeout__c));
                } else {
                    request2.setTimeout(60000);
                }
    
                request2.setBody(requestBody);
                system.debug('DML request-->' + request2);
                system.debug('DML request body-->' + request2.getBody());
                HttpResponse response = http2.send(request2);
                system.debug('status=' + response.getStatus());
                system.debug('getStatusCode=' + response.getStatusCode());
                system.debug('response body=' + response.getBody());
                if (response.getStatusCode() == 201 || response.getStatusCode() == 200){
                    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                    List<Object> resultEntitlementIdList = (List<Object>)results.get('entitlements');
                    Map<String, Object> resultObj = (Map<String, Object>)resultEntitlementIdList[0];
    
                    Map<String, Object> resultObj1 = (Map<String, Object>)resultobj.get('entitlement');
                    String tempEID = (String) resultObj1.get('eId');
    
                    if (!String.isBlank(tempEID) && odr.get('EID__c') == null) {
                        system.debug('++eid entered ' + odr.get('EID__c'));
                        String Eidquo = (String)odr.get('EID__c');
                        if (String.isBlank(Eidquo) || (!String.isBlank(Eidquo) && !Eidquo.equalsIgnoreCase(tempEID))){
                            odr.put('EID__c' , tempEID);
                        }
                    }
                    system.debug('++eid entered ' + odr);
    
                    odr.put('Last_Sync__c' , system.now());
                    odr.put('Sync_Error__c','');
                    odr.put('Warning__c', getSentinelKeyWarning(resultObj));
                    try {
                        Schema.SObjectType quotjson = getQuoteJsonObjectType();
                        sObject quoteJson = quotjson.newSObject();
                        List<SObject> orderJsonList = new List<SObject>();
                        List<Attachment> attachmentsToinsert = new List<Attachment>();
                        List<Attachment> attachmentsToUpdate = new List<Attachment>();
                        Id quotid =  (Id)odr.get('id');
                        string orderJsonList1 ='Select id, '+ quoteFieldNameInQuoteJsonObject +' ,';
                        string orderJsonList2 = '(Select Id, ParentId, Name, ContentType From Attachments)';
                        string orderJsonList3 = 'from ' + quoteJsonObjectName + ' where ';
                        String orderJsonListfinal= (orderJsonList1 + ' ' + orderJsonList2 + ' ' + orderJsonList3 + ' ' + quoteFieldNameInQuoteJsonObject + '= :quotid'); 
                        orderJsonList = Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(orderJsonListfinal));
                   
                        if (orderJsonList != null && orderJsonList.size() > 0) {
                            List<Attachment> attachmentlist = (List<Attachment>)orderJsonList[0].getSObjects('Attachments');
                            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(id = attachmentlist[0].id);
                                    
                            attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(response.getBody());
                            attachment.Name = String.valueOf('JSON_' + system.today() + '.json');
                            attachmentsToUpdate.add(attachment);
                        } else {
                            try {
                                Quote_JSON__c orderJson = new Quote_JSON__c();
                                if (Schema.sObjectType.Quote_JSON__c.isCreateable()) {
                                    orderJson.put(quoteFieldNameInQuoteJsonObject , odr.id);
                                    insert orderJson;
                                } else {                   
                                    Object[] data = new Object[] { 'Create', quoteJsonObjectName, 'table'  };
                                    throw new SentinelException(string.format(permissionErrorMessageFormat, data));
                                }
                                Attachment attachment = New Attachment();
                                attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(response.getBody());
                                attachment.Name = String.valueOf('JSON_' + system.today() + '.json');
                                attachment.ParentId = orderJson.id;
                                attachmentsToinsert.add(attachment);
                            } catch(Exception exp) {
                                System.debug('Not able to create the Quote JSON record due to ' + exp.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        if(!attachmentsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.isUpdateable()){
                                update attachmentsToUpdate;
                                }
                        }
                        if(!attachmentsToinsert.isEmpty()) {
                            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.isCreateable()) {
                                Object[] data = new Object[] { 'Create', 'Attachment', 'table'  };
                                system.debug(string.format(permissionErrorMessageFormat, data));
                            } else {
                                insert attachmentsToinsert;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(Exception exp) {
                        System.debug('Not able to update the data into Quote_JSON__C table due to ' + exp.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    String errorbody = JSON.serialize(response.getBody());
                    if (errorbody.length() > 131070){
                        odr.put('Sync_Error__c' , errorbody.substring(0, 131070));
                    } else{
                        odr.put('Sync_Error__c' , errorbody.substring(0, errorbody.length()));
                    }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            odr.put('Sync_Error__c', 'Error in sync: ' + e.getMessage() + '  line number ' + e.getLineNumber());
        }
        updateQuoteObject(odr);
    }


without checking the code I dont think we can analyze much, please share the code snippet for further help

Hi prabu, I attached the code , Please look into it and provide any help or suggestion

Please also share the Util.cls code snippet to check the issue.

This method is only from Util.cls.

Please share the snippet of the method where createQuoteEntitlement is getting called from

The method looks fine, it's how you call it is the problem. Look at the top lines of the findings (except I tweaked the text a bit for readability)
// in file: classes/Util.cls
L 1000: for (Sobject odr : orders ) {
L 1039:     jsonObj = (EntitlementWrapper) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, EntitlementWrapper.class);
L 1042:     jsonObj.status = 'Draft';
L 1301:     createQuoteEntitleMent(JSON.serialize(jsonObj), processingQuote, 'create');

does this look like your code structure around lines 1000 and 1301?
When it comes to actual execution - does it look like ultimately you do have DML in a loop?

Yes, these top lines not there in the code I attached , These are from another method with in same class in which the method 'createQuoteEntitlement' method is being called.
And Remember this createQuoteEntitlement method is not called under any loop.
Mainly the problem is with DML statement in createQuoteEntitlement right??

The code checker thinks the createQuoteEntitleMent in line 1301 called in a loop that starts in line 1000 (and that's bad because it means you ultimately do have dml in a loop, just hidden away). Is it correct? If you think it isn't, that the loop from 1000 ends earlier... you may have some misplaced / badly formatted }?

No, createQuoteEntitleMent is not called in the loop, I called this after the for loop of line 1000 ends. And ,I checked the entire code there is  no misplaces/badly formatted } .

Any chance you can post whole file? If you're sure it's a false positive you could try reporting a bug to SF / Checkmarx themselves. But if it's a FP and you've run the check in order to get published on Appexchange - you can just include your explanation in the FP file you need to submit as part of the review.

Is there any other way to share the file with you personally?? I can't share that publicly here itself..

Send me a message at linkedin.com/in/tomasz-duda ? No idea if it'll let you attach right away or we need to connect first, I'll be at my desk in couple h, day trip today.
